# win 2008 r2 - iis 7.5 - doesn't have “Import Application…”

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, deployment, .net, visual-studio-2010

i have the local developement machine (win 7) with iis 7.5.7600 and i can deploy a website from .zip file that was generated with visual studio 2010 using "Import Application..." link in an iis website

However the win 2008 r2 server that has same iis version doesn't have "Import Application..." link, it only has "add application from gallery"

the question is how do i deploy it on the server?

***removed secondary question****

using framework 4

Comment: I suggest removing the second part of this question, getting some more info and posting a separate question entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing components.  The default install doesn't have the import feature.  You'll need Web Deploy added into the mix.  [Download web deploy here.](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) That should do the trick.  Here's [A little more detail](http://randypaulo.wordpress.com/2011/08/22/iis-7-5-missing-import-application-deployment/) on this solution.

Edit:  you'll need to restart the service after adding the component.

Comment: tnx i did.... also had to restart server for it to show

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect restart server part.  Thanks!